# Ukrainian Citizen traveling from Canada to Frankfurt to Warsaw to Lviv. Schengen visa needed?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, ukrainian-citizens

I am a Ukrainian citizen living in Canada.
I am taking a vacation to Ukraine and I am looking at flight options.

Do I need a Schengen visa if I make two stops in the EU, even if I do not leave the airport?
It is extremely hard for me to get a Schengen visa as I would need to travel to Vancouver to get this, which is an hour flight or 12 hour drive!!

My flight options are as follows;
Edmonton (Canada) - Frankfurt (Germany) - Warsaw (Poland) - Lviv (Ukraine)

OR

Edmonton (Canada) - Calgary (Canada) - London (UK)  - Warsaw (Poland) - Lviv (Ukraine)

I was told by a friend that she had problems when trying to transit between two Schengen countries, without a Schengen visa, even if she was not walking out of either airport, with Ukraine as her final destination.

UK is not schengen, does this mean that I can transit between Canada-UK-Schengen-Ukraine without problem?

Comment: You are right that you need a Schengen visa for an intra-schengen flight, but you also make the impression that these are the only two possible itineraries from Edmonton to Lviv? Even if I can't find any connection with only one transfer, it seams easy enough to find itineraries with one stop in Toronto, Montreal or Kiew and only the second stop somewhere else in Europe, making it possible to transfer without a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2):

Flights between two airports in different Schengen countries are *domestic* flights within the Schengen area. That means flying Edmonton - Frankfurt - Warsaw - Lviv means you enter the Schengen area in Frankfurt and leave it in Warsaw. How you move between Frankfurt and Warsaw doesn't matter all that much.

You would not be in transit.